# Каким образом изменить размер шрифта в элементе ComboBox?

Tags: css, extjs, combobox

Каким образом изменить размер шрифта в элементе ComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос более неактуален.

Если кому интересно то размер шрифта меняется в параметре `fieldStyle`:

```
fieldStyle: {
    'font-size': "25px"
},
```